# Omnipay SecurePay returns HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: omnipay, securepay

I've successfully installed this extension(v1.7) in Civicrm 4.6 and created a payment processor omnipay_SecurePay_DirectPost.

But it always returns 'yoursite.com is currently unable to handle this request (HTTP ERROR 500)' after I filled in the credit card details and hit the submit button.

The website runs PHP5.6, Drupal 7 and Civicrm 4.6.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check server error log for the real error message.

Comment: To get a better response you should include some of your code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: v1.7 of which extension? Omnipay is currently at v2.0+